# jQuery validation help

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

**//in here i want to insert only numbers.how can i do that?**

```
function validate_proprty_price()
    {
        if($("#proprty_price").val() == '')
        {
            proprty_price.addClass("error");
            proprty_price_span.text("Please Enter Price");
            proprty_price_span.addClass("message_error2");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            proprty_price.removeClass("error");
            proprty_price_span.text("");
            proprty_price_span.removeClass("message_error2");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to convert any string that is not a number with `Number` will return `NaN`, so:

```
var price = $("#proprty_price").val();
if (isNaN(Number(price)) {
    // not a number, error message
}
```

Comment: /*not working */                                                 function validate_proprty_price()
 {
  if (isNaN(Number(price)) 
  {
   proprty_price.addClass("error");
   proprty_price_span.text("Please Enter Price");
   proprty_price_span.addClass("message_error2");
   return false;
  }
  else{
   proprty_price.removeClass("error");
   proprty_price_span.text("");
   proprty_price_span.removeClass("message_error2");
   return true;
  }
 }

Answer (score 1):

Append [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) script to your code like:

```
<script 
    type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js">
</script>
```

and just add `number` and `required` as a class to your input as

```
<input id="price" class="required number" />
```